# Unable to read data from netcat using spark

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, apache-spark

I have created two different python files. 1- for reading data from a csv file and sending over the netcat server. 2- reading data from the net cat server.

I am able to send the data over to the net cat server. However, the second file is unable to read the using spark socketStream from the netcat server. The interesting part is if I manually enter the data over netcat terminal, the program is able to read it.

```
#Client code:

import socket
import time

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8888
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
i = 0
with open("Only-R80711-SC.csv", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        if i <= 100:
            print(line)
            s.send(line.encode('utf-8'))
            i = i + 1
        else:
            i = 0
            time.sleep(0)
print("Done sending")
s.close()

#server code
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "NetworkWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 8888)

lines.pprint()
ssc.start()             # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  # Wait for the computation to terminate
```